# I want to change the android Notification Title and Content to another language(to "Sinhala") How can i do that?

Tags: android, unicode, notifications

This is my sample code that i used to generate notifications. So far i was able to get English Notifications. But now i want to get **another language** notifications on the notification bar ("[Sinhala](http://symbolcodes.tlt.psu.edu/bylanguage/sinhalachart.html#top)" )

```
    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle("My notification ")
            .setContentText("Hello World!");

    mBuilder.setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION));
    // Creates an explicit intent for an Activity in your app
    Intent resultIntent = new Intent(context, View.class);

    // The stack builder object will contain an artificial back stack for the
    // started Activity.
    // This ensures that navigating backward from the Activity leads out of
    // your application to the Home screen.
    TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(context);
    // Adds the back stack for the Intent (but not the Intent itself)
    stackBuilder.addParentStack(View.class);
    // Adds the Intent that starts the Activity to the top of the stack
    stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
    PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
            stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(
                0,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
            );
    mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
    NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
        (NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    // mId allows you to update the notification later on.
    mNotificationManager.notify(0, mBuilder.build());
```

Comment: So have you providing multiple language support on your app ?

Answer (score 2):

(i)Add any sinhala TTF file to the assets directory in the project(copy and paste).
[image]

For a sample create main.xml file using two edit text filed and a button.

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:weightSum="1">
    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent" android:id="@+id/linearLayout1" android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <EditText android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/editText1" android:layout_width="match_parent">
            <requestFocus></requestFocus>
        </EditText>
    </LinearLayout>
    <Button android:text="Tnkak" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/button1" android:layout_width="104dp"></Button>
    <EditText android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/editText2" android:layout_width="match_parent"></EditText>
</LinearLayout>
```

android:text="Tnkak", this English letters are related to Sinhala ඔබන්න(Click) word.

In LanguageAppActivity class

package com.languageapp;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

```
public class LanguageAppActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
 /** Called when the activity is first created. */ 
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        Button myButton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        Typeface type=Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "ARADANA.TTF");
        myButton.setTypeface(type);
        myButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
     // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"ARADANA.TTF");
     EditText et=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
     et.setTypeface(tf);
     EditText editText=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
     et.setText(editText.getText());  
    } 
}
```

[image]

You can do the same thing for your title and notification bar!

Comment: Yes thank bro. i already found this link. But the problem that i faced while using this code is, Using the Typeface. Do you know how to bind that to .setContentTitle("My notification ").

Comment: Get the id of your tile bar, rest is same as above!